# How do I filter some data that I just fetch/get from a spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram-bot, google-sheets-api

I'm calling/fetching some data by Name from a spreadsheet, which the output of my current code is:

| No. | Name | XXX | Location | Status | Date | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | AAAAAAAAAAAAA | XXX | XXXXXXXXXXXX | AAA | 7-Sep-22 | 163 Days |
| 2. | AAAAAAAAAAAAA | XXX | XXXXXXXXXXXX | BBB | 4-Mar-22 | 135 Days |
| 3. | AAAAAAAAAAAAA | XXX | XXXXXXXXXXXX | CCC | 6-Jun-22 | 34 Days |
| 4. | AAAAAAAAAAAAA | XXX | XXXXXXXXXXXX | DDD | 6-Oct-22 | 5 Daysv |
| 5. | AAAAAAAAAAAAA | XXX | XXXXXXXXXXXX | EEE | 23-Dec-22 | 145 Days |
| 6. | AAAAAAAAAAAAA | XXX | XXXXXXXXXXXX | FFF | 12-Jan-22 | 6 Days |

But the problem is I need to filter "AAA", "CCC", and "FFF", so that the column that has "AAA", "CCC", and "FFF" doesn't come out to be part of the output, and the output will be like this:

| ¬No. | Name | XXX | Location | Status | Date | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | AAAAAAAAAAAAA | XXX | XXXXXXXXXXXX | BBB | 4-Mar-22 | 135 Days |
| 2. | AAAAAAAAAAAAA | XXX | XXXXXXXXXXXX | DDD | 6-Oct-22 | 5 Days |
| 3. | AAAAAAAAAAAAA | XXX | XXXXXXXXXXXX | EEE | 23-Dec-22 | 145 Days |

How do I do that?

Here's my code:

```
function GetAllProject() {
  var rangeName = '//';
  var rows = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(SheetData, rangeName).values;
  return rows;
}

const WaspangList = [//,//,//]

function SearchProjectbyWaspang(Name) {

  if (WaspangList.indexOf(Name.toUpperCase()) == -1) return "The name is not registered!" 

  var project = GetAllProject();
  var no = 1;
  var num = 1;
  const data = [];

  var table = '<b>No. | Name| XXX | Location | Status | Date | Days</b>\n';

  for (var row = 0; row < project.length; row++) {
    if (project[row][7] == Name.toUpperCase()) {
      var resi = num++ + ". | " + project[row][3] + " | " + project[row][5] + " | " + project[row][6] + " | " + project[row][10] + " | " + project[row][12] + " | " + project[row][80] + " Days" + '\n\n';
      data.push(resi);
    }
  }

  var join= table + data;
  var clearComa = join.toString();
  var dataNew = clearComa.replaceAll(",", "")
  return dataNew;
}

function RunSearchProjectbyWaspang() {
  WaspangList.forEach(Name => {
    let getData = SearchProjectbyWaspang(Name)
    let send = sendText(-xxxxxxxxxxx, getData)
    Logger.log("Successfully sent data : " + Name)
  })
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and your question. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And also, I cannot understand your goal. Do you want to edit the existing Spreadsheet in your expected situation by overwriting with the new values? Or, do you want to retrieve the filtered values from your sample input sheet without changing the existing sheet?

Comment: Although unfortunately, I cannot still understand the relationship between your showing script and your question, from the 2 tables in your question, I proposed a sample script for achieving your expected result. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize. @Rubén I appreciate your edit. I wish I could upvote the edit.

Comment: dear @Tanaike, i'm sorry if my question is kind of confusing or hard to understand, but i'm trying my best to explain my problem. so the relation between the code and my question is that the code I attach is explaining how can I get the first table.And I need another code to achieve the second table.

Comment: The step I imagined to achieve this is: fetch the data by "a Name" from a spreadsheet that containing many other Names (already did this, first table as the result), then filtering the Status row by excluding "AAA", "CCC", and "FFF" from the table, then print out the result which is the second table that I need to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have already posted an answer. Can you confirm it? In my sample script, the sheet can be updated by the filtered values.

Comment: Im so sorry but unfortunately your answer seems cannot solve my problem. I don't want to change anything in the spreadsheet, the table in the question is not a spreadsheet table, it's the result of my code that I attach.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I don't want to change anything in the spreadsheet, the table in the question is not a spreadsheet table, it's the result of my code that I attach.`, my proposed script doesn't edit the Spreadsheet when `range.clearContent().offset(0, 0, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);` is not used. So, I cannot understand your reply. So, in this case, I have to delete my answer. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I think that I have to study English more.

Comment: Im so sorry, but thank you so much for trying to help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the reason that my answer was not useful for your situation is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to study English more.